# Finite bracketing integral implies convergence in probability

Tags: probability, convergence, entropy

In a paper I am reading, the following result is used. If $(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{F}) $  is a measurable space, $\mathcal{G}$ is a class of functions with elements $f : \mathcal{X} \to \mathbb{R}$. We assume $\mathcal{G}$ is a bounded metric space. Then I wish to show that if

$$
\int_{0}^R\sqrt{H_B(u,\mathcal{G},L_2(P))}du < \infty
$$

where $H_B(u,\mathcal{G},L_2(P))$ is the bracketing entropy, then

$$
\sup_{f \in \mathcal{G}} \Big| \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nf(X_i)-\mathbb{E}(f(X)) \Big| \to 0
$$
in probability. Here, $R$ is a bound on the distance between functions in $\mathcal{G}$, i.e.

$$
\sup_{f_1,f_2 \in \mathcal{G}} d(f_1,f_2) < R.
$$

I have looked various resources on empirical process theory, for example page 50 of [http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~bodhi/Talks/Emp-Proc-Lecture-Notes.pdf#page50](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Ebodhi/Talks/Emp-Proc-Lecture-Notes.pdf#page50), but to no avail. The paper where it has been used is page 3 of https://projecteuclid.org/journals/supplementalcontent/10.1214/14-AOS1260/suppdf_1.pdf